# Ignoring the input character

Tags: c++, iostream

So, I want to use the cin.ignore(200,'\n') to input a line and save it into a string without saving the \n as the string. But when I do:

```
cin.ignore(200,'\n');
getline(cin,name);
```

It asks me to input something twice, but I just want to ask me once and save it into name.

I've read something about the cin.clear(), but I think it's not what I need, or perhaps, I missunderstood what that clear does.

Thanks!

Comment: Its asking you twice because you are ignoring the first input. why do you need to use *ignore()* before *getline()*? *getline()* will not read the new line character to the string anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`cin.ignore(n, ch)` *discards* characters from the stream associated with `std::cin` until either `n` characters have been skipped, or until `ch` is seen. The `cin.ignore(200, '\n');` is discarding the first input, up to the newline character. You're then getting a line, which will accept your second input.

You may need to use the `cin.ignore(n, ch);` construct if you want to read a line *immediately after* you perform a whitespace-delimited input operation, like

```
int i = 0;
std::cin >> i; // reads an integer, possibly leaving a '\n' in the stream
std::cin.ignore(200, '\n'); // reads and discards until a newline is seen
std::string name;
std::getline(std::cin, name); // reads a full line
```

In your case, if you haven't done any whitespace-delimited input, the `cin.ignore` is skipping over the first attempt to provide your line input. You should simply use std::getline immediately. The newline character at the end of the line is *not* appended to the string, but it is removed from the input stream.

The [documentation for `std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) explains this in the "Notes" section.

---

For a more robust line input function, where you cannot be sure whether the previous input operation left a newline character (or whatever delimiter you're using) on the stream, you can do something like:

```
char ch;
std::cin.peek(ch);
if (ch == '\n') {
    std::cin.ignore(1, '\n'); // or std::cin.get(ch);
}
std::string line;
std::getline(std::cin, line);
```

The [`peek`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/peek) member function will return the next character to be read, without removing it from the stream. If it's a newline, you can go ahead and ignore it. Otherwise, the `getline` call will read the entire line, including the character you just peeked at.

Alternatively, if you only want to consume whitespace, you can use the [`std::ws`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/ws) manipulator.

Comment: I think you have a typo in your answer *"std::readline"*, i think you meant to say *std::getline* and +1 for the alternative suggestion.

Comment: @bkVnet Thanks. I did indeed mean `std::getline`! Edited accordingly.

Comment: @bkVnet So... What if I wanted to keep reading lines...? Imagine my code was something like this:
with everything declared and included.

        while (true){
             getline(cin,name);
             cout << name << endl;
       }

If i had cin.ignore(100,'\n') before the while loop, it'd ask me for an input first, which I don't want...

Comment: @magalenyo you don't have to put *cin.ignore()* before the loop. And you need to have an exit condition from your loop.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `ignore()` in this case. `getline()` will not put the new line character to the string.

The reason its asking you for an input twice is because the `ignore()` function is removing until your first *200* input characters or up to the newline(your deliminator) so the next `getline()` probably will not have anything to read thus asking you for input(unless of course your first input contains more than 200 characters,in that case it will read the remaining characters in the buffer).

[`std::getline()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) will not add the **delimiter** character to the string that is read, which is the **newline character** by default.